# SQL Server: issues with field length control

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-warehouse, varchar

Were are facing a big problem with string length control in SQL Server 2008.

A brief recap of our system:

- import data in a persistent staging area from `*.txt` file (semicolon as separator), using bulk insert in SQL Server environment;
- in PSA table all columns are `varchar(MAX)`;
- cleaning operations using insert statement based on a select with multiple where conditions.

The problem we deal with is on a single column type and length, in fact in data warehouse level it has to be numeric and its lengths must not exceed 13 digits.

The select is the following:

```
select cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(data_giacenza)) as numeric), 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(codice_socio)), 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(codice_gln)), 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(tipo_gln)), 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(codice_articolo_socio)), 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(codice_ean_prodotto)), 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(codice_ecat_prodotto)), 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(famiglia)), 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(marca)),
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(classificazione_liv_1)), 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(classificazione_liv_2)),
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(classificazione_liv_3)), 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(classificazione_liv_4)), 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(modello)), 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(descrizione_articolo)), 
                        cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(giacenza)) as numeric),
                        cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(acquistato)) as numeric), 'X' FROM psa_stock a
                          where EXISTS 
                          ( 
                          SELECT 0 
                          FROM(
                                SELECT 
                                            data_giacenza
                                           ,codice_socio
                                                 ,codice_gln
                                                 ,codice_articolo_socio
                                                 FROM psa_stock 
            where
                        LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(data_giacenza))) = 8 and LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(codice_socio))) = 3
                  and LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(codice_gln))) = 13 and LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(tipo_gln))) = 3 
                  and LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(codice_articolo_socio))) <= 15 
                  and (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(codice_ean_prodotto))) <= 13 or LEN(ISNULL(codice_ean_prodotto, '')) = 0) 
                  and (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(codice_ecat_prodotto))) = 9 or LEN(ISNULL(codice_ecat_prodotto, '')) = 0)
                  and LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(famiglia))) = 2
                  and (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(marca))) <= 20 or LEN(ISNULL(marca, '')) = 0)
                  and (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(modello))) <= 30 or LEN(ISNULL(modello, '')) = 0)
                  and (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(descrizione_articolo))) <= 50 or LEN(ISNULL(descrizione_articolo, '')) = 0)
                  and LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(giacenza))) <= 5
                  and LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(acquistato))) <= 5 
                  and (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(classificazione_liv_1))) <= 15 or LEN(ISNULL(classificazione_liv_1, '')) = 0)
                  and (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(classificazione_liv_2))) <= 15 or LEN(ISNULL(classificazione_liv_2, '')) = 0)
                  and (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(classificazione_liv_3))) <= 15 or LEN(ISNULL(classificazione_liv_3, '')) = 0)
                  and (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(classificazione_liv_4))) <= 15 or LEN(ISNULL(classificazione_liv_4, '')) = 0)
                  and ISNUMERIC(ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE(data_giacenza, ' ', '')))) = 1 
                  and ISNUMERIC(ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE(codice_gln, ' ', '')))) = 1 
                  and ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(giacenza, ' ', '')))) = 1 and charindex(',', giacenza) = 0
                  and ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(acquistato, ' ', '')))) = 1 
                  and ISNUMERIC(ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE(codice_ean_prodotto, ' ', '')))) = 1
                  and ISNUMERIC(ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE(codice_ecat_prodotto, ' ', '')))) = 1
                  and codice_socio in (select codice_socio from ana_socio)
                  and tipo_gln in (select tipo from ana_gln)
                  and codice_gln in (select codice_gln from dw_key_gln)
                  group by 
               data_giacenza
              ,codice_socio
                  ,codice_gln
                  ,codice_articolo_socio
                             having COUNT (*) = 1
                  ) b
          where 
                a.data_giacenza = b.data_giacenza and
                a.codice_articolo_socio = b.codice_articolo_socio and
                    a.codice_socio = b.codice_socio and
                    a.codice_gln = b.codice_gln)
```

The critical field is `codice_ean_prodotto`.

In fact, it allows to consider also values as `SEAGAT7636490026751,NE20000003039,NE20000002168` which are not numeric and, the first, overlap maximum dimensions.

As result, the insert statement gives back

> String o binary data would be truncated

error and fails the insertion.

Thanks in advance! I look forward your help!!!

Enrico

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing that query, and adding `codice_ean_prodotto = 'NE20000003039'` to the where clause? Be sure that these are the actual field that is giving you the problem. If the select returns a row with that where clause, then something's wrong with the logic.

I'm leaning towards your `having COUNT (*) = 1` clause in the EXISTS subquery - is it possible to have more than one record for these specific keys? As long as your PK is made up of those 4 fields `(data_giacenza, codice_articolo_socio, codice_socio, codice_gln)`, you shouldn't need the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses at all. If you're not joining on your primary key, it could be that it is the culprit.

It's hard to tell without seeing your data model, however.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.
In the inner select, we were excluding from the selection all records not respecting format constraints and duplication (the meaning of `count(*)=1`), extracting only the PK of the destination table.
But when selecting with PK we retrieve also those record that were duplicates, but were excluded by the format constraint, leading the insert to error due to dimension issues.

Now I divided the steps:

1. Duplicates lookup and deletion
2. Selection with format constraints

It works!